# Cron error: Exception 'yii\base\InvalidConfigException' with message 'The configuration for the "user" component must contain a "class" element.'

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, extend, yii2-basic-app

I followed code this page https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/646/how-to-implement-cron-in-yii-2

And I test cron but fails

$ php yii test/index

Exception 'yii\base\InvalidConfigException' with message 'The configuration for the "user" component must contain a "class" element.'

in /var/www/yiidemo/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/ServiceLocator.php:205

Stack trace:

```
#0 /var/www/yiidemo/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/ServiceLocator.php(261): yii\di\ServiceLocator->set('user', Array)
#1 /var/www/yiidemo/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Component.php(180): yii\di\ServiceLocator->setComponents(Array)
#2 /var/www/yiidemo/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php(546): yii\base\Component->__set('components', Array)
#3 /var/www/yiidemo/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/BaseObject.php(107): yii\BaseYii::configure(Object(yii\console\Application), Array)
#4 /var/www/yiidemo/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(206): yii\base\BaseObject->__construct(Array)
#5 /var/www/yiidemo/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Application.php(89): yii\base\Application->__construct(Array)
#6 /var/www/yiidemo/yii(26): yii\console\Application->__construct(Array)
#7 {main}
```

I use Yii2, mongdb

My file console/config/main.php

```
$params = array_merge(
    require __DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params.php', 
    require __DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params-local.php', 
    require __DIR__ . '/params.php', 
    require __DIR__ . '/params-local.php'
);

return [
    'id' => 'app-console',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'controllerNamespace' => 'console\controllers',
    'aliases' => [
        '@bower' => '@vendor/bower-asset',
        '@npm'   => '@vendor/npm-asset',
    ],
    'controllerMap' => [
        'fixture' => [
            'class' => 'yii\console\controllers\FixtureController',
            'namespace' => 'common\fixtures',
        ],
    ],
    'components' => [
        'log' => [
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
         'user' => [
             'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
             'enableAutoLogin' => true,
         ]
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];
```

Comment: when using yii console your `console/config/main.php` is used and you do not need to define a user component in the console config, just remove it from the components section and it will work

Comment: hi @MuhammadOmerAslam , 
Please help me reconfigure file main.php
Thanksss!

Comment: Hi @MuhammadOmerAslam, I have removed this code
`'user' => [
             'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
             'enableAutoLogin' => true,
         ]
`
But it still fails!

Comment: see the answer i added below. and what error is it throwing

Comment: On locahost it runs file main-local.php, but it still fails!

Comment: can you add your `main-local.php` file

Comment: yeah on localhost will use the `console/config/main-local.php` file change there too along with `console/config/main.php` which will be used for production ENV

Comment: I changed the code in file main-local.php similar to file main.php, but it still fails
`Exception 'yii\base\UnknownPropertyException' with message 'Getting unknown property: yii\console\Response::cookies' in /home/yiidemo.com/public_html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Component.php:154`

Comment: hmm... are you using any laguage extension `lajax/yii2-language-picker`? are there configurations in the `common/config/main.php` related to the extension ?

Comment: share your `common/config/main.php` or `common/config/main-local.php` if any config added there too.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Note there are no sessions in the console application so you don't need to add the `session` component if there is please remove them.

---

Because `user` is not defined in console apps, `class` is required. In web app it's defined by default so one can override only some properties relying on defaults. You need to either remove the following section

```
'user' => [
      'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
      'enableAutoLogin' => true,
 ]
```

or add the `class` for the user component

```
'user' => [
      'class' => 'yii\web\User',
      'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
 ]
```

in `console/config/main.php` and the local config file `console/config/main-local.php`.

Comment: `php yii test/index`
`Exception 'yii\base\UnknownPropertyException' with message 'Getting unknown property: yii\console\Response::cookies'`

`in /home/yiidemo.com/public_html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Component.php:154`

Comment: hi u, How to delete `session`